# Loop in a Loop with index less than the stopped one

Tags: abap

I have the following problem and I need an idea how to overcome?
I have 2 identical **ITABs:** ITAB1 and ITAB2 with 60 records.
I am looping in the 1st ITAB and when I am finding a record I am looping in the 2nd ITAB with INDEX = sy-tabix of the 1st one:

```
LOOP at ITAB1 where COL = '001'.
  lv_tabix = sy-tabix.
  * Do STH.
  LOOP at ITAB2 FROM lv_tabix
    * do sth
    EXIT.
  ENDCASE.
ENDCASE.
```

Lets suppose that I am looping the 2nd ITAB with lv_tabix = 17 and, I am exiting from the 2nd when its tabix=22.
So I am returning in the 1st ITAB do sth and, I am starting the loop of the 2nd ITAB with lv_tabix=21.
I have noticed that the loop of the 2nd ITAB cannot start from a record (21) which is less than the one it was stopped (22).

Am I right?

**How can I overcome this problem?**

Thanks
Elias

Comment: post some data please

Comment: Makis the code is too big to post it but the concept is the one that counts. When I am exiting from the loop of ITAB2 its tabix is equal to 22. When I am starting again the Loop of ITAB2 the lv_tabix is equal to 21. It seems that the loop cannot start from Index that it is less than the index it stops. Can we overcome this restriction?

Comment: When you are out of the inner loop, means back in the 1st loop the sy-tabix has to be set back to the value of the 1st loop (automatically by the system). Post your code!

Comment: The StackOverflow concept is brilliant because people should create a dedicated [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (restart from scratch, divide and conquer -> no need of 60 rows, 2 rows in itab1 and 2 rows in itab2 are enough). If you had done it (and that's quite easy to do as Florian demonstrated), you would have seen by yourself that your assumption is incorrect and that you should investigate what the issue really is.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce your problem.

```
DATA(table_1) = VALUE string_table( ( `A` ) ( `B` ) ( `C` ) ( `D` ) ).
DATA(table_2) = VALUE string_table( ( `A` ) ( `B` ) ( `C` ) ( `D` ) ).

LOOP AT table_1 INTO DATA(row_1).
  DATA(start_index) = sy-tabix.
  LOOP AT table_2 INTO DATA(row_2) FROM start_index.
    IF row_2 = `C`.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.
```

works fine, although in the first outer loop iteration it exits the inner loop at `sy-tabix = 3` and in the second outer loop iteration restarts the inner loop with the lower `start_index = 2`.